# How to create a 2 bit gif from tiff file in dotnet

Tags: .net, tiff, gif

I have used Bitmap class to convert tiff to Gif but it couldn't make the image 2 bit possible for have less size. 
Notice that bitmap class could create images with this pixel format : 
1, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 (bits)
But my need is 2 bit.
Unfortunately Gdi+ do not support 2bpp. 
Is there any source or library to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDI+ only supports 1bpp,4bpp,8bpp for GIF output. Although the GIF specs allow other color depths, it's not supported by GDI+.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx

Comment: what can i do to use 2bpp? there is nothing in them for 2bit (2bpp)!

Comment: Your only option is to use a third-party library, or write the code for saving to a GIF file yourself