# How to create GIF file from other format file in C++

Tags: c++, image, gif

I want to create 2 bits per pixel GIF files in VC environment from a TIFF file.

Is there any free library or maybe source that could help me?

Or how can I do it myself?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750091/how-to-create-a-2-bit-gif-from-tiff-file-in-dotnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either OpenIL ( http://openil.sourceforge.net/ ), which is a C library, or if you really want a C++ only solution, Magick++ ( http://www.imagemagick.org/www/Magick++/ )

Answer (score -1):

*Assuming "VC environment" means using VC++ to make a win32 executable:*

You could [invoke](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) using `CreateProcess()`.